# KeyError: "None of [Index(['file_path'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-enhancement

I tried to run this [file](https://github.com/AndyHuang1995/Image-Contrast-Enhancement/blob/master/ying.py) and it's giving me the following error while trying to call the function. I couldn't understand what is causing this error. I want to do some image enhancement so that my model can better understand them while training. Any other suggestions or codes to do the same are welcome.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DIP_Ankita/image_corrector.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = data[['file_path']]
  File "C:\Users\srchirag27\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3001, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)
  File "C:\Users\srchirag27\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1285, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\Users\srchirag27\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1092, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
  File "C:\Users\srchirag27\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1177, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
KeyError: "None of [Index(['file_path'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: What code did you run?

Comment: I have mentioned the code in the link https://github.com/AndyHuang1995/Image-Contrast-Enhancement/blob/master/ying.py

Answer (score 1):

There was some issue with the file being saved. The previously written code was being called rather than the updated one. I deleted the file and then created another one with the same script and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

data[['file_path']] creates a new dataframe containing only one column - *file_path*.

Check data.columns and if the required column is not there then you need to ensure that column is being passed.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have data[['file_path']] anywhere in my code

Comment: Upload code to image_corrector.py file? That is the one which is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing np before conj, `np.conj()` in your line 10

Comment: It was called on the numpy object. I think it should have worked fine.

Comment: Did you try this? `dt0_h = np.vstack((np.diff(fin, n=1, axis=1).np.conj().T, fin[:,0].np.conj().T-fin[:,-1].np.conj().T)).np.conj().T`